# Problem with PHP string Interprolation by trying to set variable in php equal to html code

Tags: php

I am trying to set a variable equal to some html code. Inside of the html code I want the values of some other php variables to be included inside of it. Here is an example of my code. I was able to set the php variable equal to the html code however I was not able to include php variables inside of the html code. Please help. Thanks in advance I tried using `<?php echo $paypal ?>` and that didn't work. I also tried putting just the variable name however that doesn't set the value and only sets the name of the variable inside the code here.

```
paypalsend = '
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="{$paypal}">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{$product}">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$price}">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="{$shipping}">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

';
```

Comment: Variables will not be parsed between single quotes

Comment: When I add double quotes I get a syntax error because I have quotes around https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) makes this easy

```
<?php

$paypalsend = <<<EOF
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="{$paypal}">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{$product}">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{$price}">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="{$shipping}">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

EOF;
```

Comment: Dude I love you man! I have spent sooo much time trying to figure out how to do this! Thank you!